# How to convert datetime to ago format 2019-02-28T11:30:00.000Z?

Tags: java, android

I have a date like 2019-02-28T11:30:00.000Z format, I want to convert it into ago or before format I use this but it shows ago format incorrect please solve this problem.

```
public class CustomDateFormat {
public static String DateToTimeFormat(String oldstringDate) {
    PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
    String isTime = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",new Locale(getCountry()));
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = sdf.parse(oldstringDate);
        isTime = p.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isTime;
}

public static String DateFormat(String oldstringDate) {
    String newDate;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy", 
new Locale(getCountry()));
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", new Locale(getCountry())).parse(oldstringDate);
        newDate = dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        newDate = oldstringDate;
    }
    return newDate;
}

public static String getCountry() {
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    String country = String.valueOf(locale.getCountry());
    return country.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Could you elaborate, on what is the expected format?

Comment: What does "ago or before format" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have something to find out 'ago'. Similarly you can try for 'before'

```
public String gettimeago(String ntime) {



        final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;

        final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;

        final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;

        final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;


        if (ntime != null) {

            long earlier = Long.parseLong(ntime);


            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (earlier < 1000000000000L) {

                earlier *= 1000;

            }


            if (earlier > now || earlier <= 0) {

                return null;

            }


            final long diff = now - earlier;

            if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {

                return "just now";

            } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {

                return "a minute ago";

            } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {

                return (diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago");

            } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {

                return "a hour ago";

            } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {

                return (diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago");

            } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {

                return "yesterday";

            } else {

                return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";

            }



        }


        return "";


    }
```

Comment: Sir like 20 minutes ago ,5 minutes before

Comment: I got that what do you want. This method is for getting "20 minutes ago" etc. You can try similarly for "20 min before".